# html survey statistics using a local file

Tags: javascript, php, html, storage

I am building a website, (I am new to this so I only created my website as a "complete web page" structure, having all pages and files used for the website into the same directory).

The website contains a survey whose results are saved in a `file.txt` that needs to be accessed by multiple users. I want to make some statistics out of that data.

I first tried using Javascript to read from the file by using some AJAX (`XMLHttpRequest`):

```
function readfile() {
    var f = new XMLHttpRequest();
    f.open("GET","data.txt", false);
    f.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if(f.readyState === 4) {
            var content = f.responseText;
            document.getElementById("test").innerHTML = content;
        }
    }
}
```

but it didn't work.

I also tried "echoing" the content of the file into a Javascript variable with PHP and then put it on the page, but it still does not work, plus I don't know how to do the other way around operation (from js to PHP variable).

The last thing I tried are the `window.localStorage` and `window.SessionStorage` but then this does not do the thing to me because I want the data to be available across browsers and even when the website is accessed from different devices.

Another thing that I tried is HTML5's `FileReader` which consists of a file input in the web page but that's not what I want because I don't want the user to chose the I/O file, for data structure issues that may occur while trying to read from or write to the file.

I hope someone of you might have the answer to this, I spent days trying to solve this and tried everything but with no outcome.

Comment: Why not plug some database to store this information in structured way like `MySQL` or if its too heavy use `sqlite`

Comment: You can find it easily on internet like https://www.udemy.com/php-mysql-tutorial/